# Unable to locate the model you have specified - CodeIgniter Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting an unable to locate model error.

```
$this->load->model('1/Gift_model');
```

My model file name is **gift_model.php** within /models/1/.

I declare the model the following way.

```
class Gift_model extends CI_Model {
```

According to CodeIgniter's documentation I'm doing it the correct way. Any suggestions? I have 5 other models named exactly the same way and they're all loading fine.

Comment: I don't think that codeigniter allows folders like `1` in it's structure.

Comment: Codeigniter lets you put models within folders inside of models. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: See here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#loading

Comment: Correct. "If your model is located in a sub-folder, include the relative path from your models folder". '1' is my sub-folder. I have numerous other models with the same structure that load in other portions of the platform.

Comment: Aaron is correct. $this->load->model('1/gift_model'); And Marcel is right - a capital letter on the file name will sometimes work like he is saying - BUT not across all platforms. so just do lower case for everything - except the first letter of a model or class. and hey while you are reading this - having a model folder named "1" - you might want to reconsider that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Make the model class name *Uppercase* `My_model`
2. Make the model php file name *Lowercase* `my_model`
3. Load the model using *Lowercase* (file name) `$this->load->model('my_model');`

Comment: 2. fixed it for me

Apparently it matters on certain environments that the PHP file name itself is uppercased. Very funny.

Answer (score 3):

`$this->load->model('1/Gift_model');` should be `$this->load->model('1/gift_model');`. Lowercase on this load argument and the php filename, uppercase on the class name within the file (you had two of three correct).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html

> Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner or in other words - **they must start with a capital letter**.

Used to be the model files started with lower case, but they changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that the the model name is Gift_model and the class name is also Gift_model

```
class Gift_model extends CI_Model
{

}
```

but loading the class is '1/gift_model' NOT 'Gift_model'

```
$this->load->model('1/gift_model');
```

hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your file name is all lowercase (`gift_model.php`) while you are loading `Gift_model` within CodeIgniter. Either change the file name to `Gift_model.php` or update your code accordingly.

Comment: According to the codeigniter doc the file name is supposed to be lowercase and you declare it uppercase and call it uppercase. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: Marcel you are correct but it does not work on all platforms so its best to just do lower case.

Comment: @PhillipJamesRoth The class should be defined with the first letter being uppercase. However, as the docs say: "The file name will be a lower case version of your class name." Similarly, the load function should load via the case of the *file* name, not the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling the parent's constructor for the model?

```
class Gift_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-> Model Class name must be Uppercase
-> Model PHP file name must be Lowercase
-> Load Model using Lowercase(filename): $this->load->model('gift_model', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner or in other words - they must start with a capital letter.

<sup>([Source: CI docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html))</sup>

Answer (score -1):

`if using codeignitor 3.1.3
every thing same otherwise showing error
class name     => My_model

file name      => My_model.php

load model     => $this->load->model('My_model');

call function  => $this->My_model->function();`

Comment: read this first , 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Loading should be lowercase, load model => $this->load->model('my_model');