# Model autoloading not working in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, heroku

I'm autoloading models like this:

```
$autoload['model'] = array('user_model','article_model','settings_model','authenticate_model');
```

And I have next files:

> models/user_model.php:

```
<?php 
class User_model extends CI_Model {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
        }
}

?>
```

And next error appears:

> Unable to locate the model you have specified: User_model

And if access this file directly:

> You don't have permission to access /application/models/user_model.php on this server.

So what can be causing the problem?

Comment: What version of codeigniter are you using?

Comment: It looks like the file user_model.php doesn't have read access for the web server

Comment: @BeatAlex the latest one from CI main page.

Comment: @gabe3886 how can I change it? I'm hosting it on heroku http://tcms.herokuapp.com/application/models/user_model.php

Comment: Change the file name to `User_model.php` instead of `user_model.php`.

Comment: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: Don't close php tag.
Leave last character be class closing curly bracket.

Comment: @Tpojka why? Is there a convention for this?

Comment: Actually it is explained in [docs](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html#php-closing-tag) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BeatAlex Said, it was the issue with the first letter of my models being in lower case. But for some reason when I was changing the name before, and pushing it with git using this command:

`git commit -a -m "broke everythink"; git push heroku master`

It wasn't changing the name of the file.

I had to delete the files, push changes, and then create them again and push them again, and now it's working.

Comment: I'm no git pro, so can't tell if that's the right command or not. Glad I could help though :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the model class name Uppercase `My_model`
2. Make the model php file name Lowercase "my_model"
3. Load the model using Lowercase (file name) `$this->load->model('my_model');`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22634263/1705099

Answer (score 0):

1. Name your model file as **U**ser_model.php (note the capital U)
2. Change the code in autoload.php to the following (again note the capital U in User_model): `$autoload['model'] = array('User_model'...`
3. Make sure the User_model.php file has the correct permissions, i.e. 755
4. You should now be able to use the model via `$this->User_model->somefunction();`