# CodeIgniter won't load model on deployment machine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I developed a small application with Codeigniter and brought it to run with vagrant and Debian. And everything was fine.

So now I'm trying to set up a virtual machine with Xubuntu 15.04. Installed the same packages (PHP as an Apache module)

Now I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to locate the model you have specified: Person_model
```

This is how I load my model:

```
$this->load->model('person_model');
```

And this is how my model actually looks like in `models/person_model.php`

```
<?php

class Person_model extends CI_Model {
  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  // ...
}
```

On Xubuntu I'm running **PHP 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.2** and on Debian I'm running **PHP 5.4.41-0+deb7u1**

Thanks for any advice and help!

Comment: Try to rename the file to Person_model.php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to locate the model you have specified - CodeIgniter Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18882329/unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified-codeigniter-issue)

Comment: @Joerg thank you! That's exactly what I missed to try and what caused the problem. If you consider writing an answer, I would accept yours!

Comment: @Nassim no it's not a duplicate since in that very issue you posted it is advised to use lower case for the file name.
//edit: Oh I didn't finish reading the answer... yes, Nassim, this partly solves my question.

Comment: No problem , glad we could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Starting with CodeIgniter 3.0, all class filenames (libraries, drivers, controllers and models) must be named in a Ucfirst-like manner or in other words - they must start with a capital letter.
>   http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-2-update-your-classes-file-names

This is CodeIgniter 3.0 coding convention which you must follow.
So your model file should be `models/Person_model.php`.

Probably you use case insentive file system (host OS is like Windows or Mac) with Vagrant shared folder . And you don't use Vagrant shared folder with Xubuntu, don't you?

Anyway, this is problem with file system, not PHP version nor OS.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same way after trying out @Joerg's post.

Comment: What is the reason to make an answer about facts, I commend hours ago?

Answer (score 0):

Alter these settings

Model File name should be - **person_model.php**

Then in controller

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))        exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Resources extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Person_model');

    }
}
```

And inside `person_model.php`

```
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Person_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

This will solve your all problems.

Read This Articles too

1. [CI Model](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)
2. [CI Controller](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html)